# How to treat a list of string like an enum in a model - ASP.net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.net Core Web API (v3.1) that accepts a model with a property that is an enum.  Example class and enum:

```
public class OrderModel 
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public OrderType OrderType { get;set; }
    ...
}

public enum OrderType 
{
    Offline = 0, 
    Checkout = 1
}
```

This is then shown in the swagger as follows:

[image]

I'd like to define a list of string, example:

```
public class OrderTypes 
{
   public List<string> GetOrderTypes() 
   {
        return new List<string> { "Offline", "Checkout" }; 
        // in reality this will be dynamically built at startup.
   }
}
```

What I'd like to do is change my model to be similar to this:

```
public class OrderModel 
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderType { get;set; }
    ...
}
```

But show the options for OrderType in a similar way as that for the enum.

Is this possible?

NOTE: My actual use case for this will be to reflect (at run-time) all of the implementations of a particular interface.  This will is an ever growing list and will grow over time - I don't want to have to maintain an enum list of these providers as they grow.

Comment: Why enum is not good enough ? What do you need string for ?

Comment: Because I want to reflect the implementors of a particular interface at run-time and use that as the available options for a model property :-)  dont want to maintain an enum list as there will be many extending implementors of this particular interface going forward

Comment: Have you looked into schema filters?
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#extend-generator-with-operation-schema--document-filters with that you can transform the resulting swagger  schema to suit your needs

Comment: Yea that only allows for samples but it's explicit enough to say here's the options for this particular string.  It just shows one sample (maybe I'm using it incorrectly though??)